# Are "rainy season" and "less rainy season" good ways to describe Amazon seasons in English scientific language?

Tags: terminology, seasons, amazon

I'm a Brazilian native. Here, the English translation to the most didactic way to express the Amazon seasons are: "rainy season", and "less rainy season", because it always rains a lot, but there is a period when there is less. Does anyone know if this is the best way to express this in English scientific language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Dry season

While not being very descriptive, 'dry season' is in general use, even for rainforests (*Af* Koppen climate, if you will). Example papers using the terminology [here](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=amazon%20dry%20season&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C47&as_sdtp=).